# Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_num_rows(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo un error en el archivo editar_proveedor.php, cada vez que intendo actualizar el proveedor me envia un fatal error y es el siguiente:** Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_num_rows(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given in D:\xampp\htdocs\Facturacion\sistema\editar_proveedor.php:44 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\Facturacion\sistema\editar_proveedor.php(44): mysqli_num_rows(false) #1 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\Facturacion\sistema\editar_proveedor.php on line 44**

Ya lo habia hecho antes con otro archivo que tiene la misma estructura, solo que en este le quite varias cosas que no necesitaba. A continuacion el codigo, agradeceria de su ayuda:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['rol'] != 1 and $_SESSION['rol'] != 2) {
    header("location:./");
}

include "../conexion.php";

    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        $alert = '';
        if (empty($_POST['proveedor']) || empty($_POST['contacto']) || empty($_POST['telefono']) || empty($_POST['direccion'])) {
            $alert = '<p class="msg_error">Todos los campos son obligatorios</p>';
        }else {
            
            $idproveedor = $_POST['id'];
            $proveedor   = $_POST['proveedor'];
            $contacto    = $_POST['contacto'];
            $telefono    = $_POST['telefono'];
            $direccion   = $_POST['direccion'];
                
            $sql_update = mysqli_query($conection, "UPDATE proveedor SET proveedor = '$proveedor', contacto= '$contacto', telefono= '$telefono', direccion='$direccion' WHERE codproveedor= $idproveedor");
    
            if ($query_update = true) {
                $alert = '<p class="msg_save">Proveedor actualizado correctamente</p>';
            }else {
                $alert = '<p class="msg_error">Error al actualizar el Proveedor     </p>';
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    //Mostrar datos video 32
    include "../conexion.php";
    if (empty($_REQUEST['id'])) {
        header('location: lista_proveedores.php');
        mysqli_close($conection);
    }
    
    $idproveedor = $_REQUEST['id'];
    
    $sql = mysqli_query($conection,"SELECT * FROM proveedor WHERE codproveedor = $idproveedor");
    
    mysqli_close($conection);
    $result_sql = mysqli_num_rows($sql); //esta es la linea 44 que genera el error 
    
    if ($result_sql == 0) {
        header('location: lista_proveedor.php');
        mysqli_close($conection);
    }else {
        while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
            $idproveedor = $data['codproveedor'];
            $proveedor   = $data['proveedor'];
            $contacto    = $data['contacto'];
            $telefono    = $data['telefono'];
            $direccion   = $data['direccion'];
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Este es el codigo html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <?php include "include/scripts.php"  ?>
    <title>Actualizar Proveedor</title> 
</head>
<body>
    <?php include "include/header.php"  ?>
    <section id="container">
        <div class="form_register">
            <h1><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i> Actualizar Proveedor </h1>
            <hr>
            <div class="alert"><?php echo isset($alert)? $alert: '';?></div>

            <form action="" method="post">

                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="value="<?php echo $idproveedor ?>>

                <label for="proveedor">Proveedor:</label>
                <input type="text" name="proveedor" id="proveedor" placeholder="Nombre del Proveedor" value="<?php echo $proveedor ?>">

                <label for="contacto">Contacto:</label>
                <input type="text" name="contacto" id`introducir el código aquí`="contacto" placeholder="Nombre Completo del Contacto" value="<?php echo $contacto ?>">

                <label for="telefono">Telefono:</label>
                <input type="number" name="telefono" id="telefono" placeholder="Telefono" value="<?php echo $telefono ?>">

                <label for="direccion">Direccion:</label>
                <input type="text" name="direccion" id="direccion" placeholder="Direccion Completa" value="<?php echo $direccion ?>">

                <button type="submit" class="btn_save"><i class="fa-solid fa-floppy-disk"></i> Actualizar Proveedor</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
    <?php include "include/footer.php" ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Estas cerrando la conexión de mysqli en la línea 43 y después la cierras de nuevo en el if. Por que no la cierras después del if, ya que pase lo que pase al final es cuando necesitas cerrarla.